# Excel paste protect formattings

Tags: vba, excel

I need to protect formatting in all my cells, when a user pastes info into a sheet.

I'm trying to catch paste events, but based on examples, using UNDO is locale sensitive. Also, UNDO will not work on a protected sheet.

I would like to write a function that, on selection change, selects cells like they have been "doubleclicked" on.

Question: how to do this?

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("protectedC")) Is Nothing Then
 Application.DoubleClick
End If
```

This does not work. So, how do I select a cell, as if it has been doubleclicked?

Comment: Maybe `Application.SendKeys "{F2}"` could help.

Comment: If you want to be certain to catch a paste event, there is quite a lot you have to catch. [This site](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/CatchPaste.asp) gives a pretty good overview. I can understand wanting to avoid implementing something like that, so @user3964075's suggestion may be your best bet.

Comment: Protect the sheet with the `UserInterfaceOny:=True` argument, then the sheet is protected but your code still has full access to manipulate it as required.